# How does Windows Backup determine what is an OS Partition

Tags: windows, backup, windows-sbs-2008

My server machine has 2 disks: a primary disk containing SBS 2008 and a second disk with an copy of Windows Server 2008 that I am not currently using (but don't want to delete at this time).

**Windows Backup is automatically selecting both disks for backup because they both contain OS installations**. I would like to exclude the second disk from backup. I have tried to hide the second disk before configuring my nightly backup, but alas it contains the boot loader (another issue to fix I guess) and therefore needs to be present.

So I am looking for a way to **temporarily configure my second drive so it won't be considered an OS drive** when setting up my nightly Windows backup. Can I rename some files/folders, or maybe modify the boot information using bcdedit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the built-in backup utility that comes with SBS 2008 you cannot exclude any drive that houses an Operating System.

You "might" be able to go into Disk Management, right click the drive and choose "change drive letter and path" and choose remove.  This will remove it from having a drive letter assignment...but I don't know if SBS will still see the volume or not during backup.  And what a pain to do this everytime you need to backup the server.

Same thing with "mountvol  /D".

The better solution would be to backup the system using something other than the built in utility for now OR unplug the 2nd disk physically and plug it back in if you really need it again.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that once the backup is scheduled it will not re-scan all drives to see if it needs to add another drive to the backup. I wonder if anyone can confirm this re-scanning behavior.

Comment: Probably easy enough to just test it.  Dismount the volume and see if the utility will recognize the drive still.  If not, let it run a backup and set the schedule.  Then you can simply start the scheduled task again after remounting the drive and see if it backs up without the drive again.